# HTC rhyme shows LOCKED when I turn it on

Tags: bootloader, htc, bootloader-lock

When I turn my HTC Rhyme phone, it just shows A page that's written ***LOCKED***  at the top and has three android icons at the bottom and have some menu items as below:

- Bootloader
- Reboot
- Reboot Bootloader
- Power Down

I've tried all of the menu items, but gained no success. Is there anything I could do to recover my phone.

Answer (score 1):

all that the locked status indicates is that the bootloader itself is actually locked...it sounds like your partitions may have gotten botched up.  Was the phone acting up prior to this, or were you attempting to root/install a custom rom?

Comment: No it was inside of a bag. And just some keys were hit by accident. That's all that could happen to my cellphone. I've done nothing to it! ;-(

Comment: What is the solution? What can I do??

Comment: Very sorry for the late response, I had forgotten about this question entirely.  If you still have the phone and haven't figured it out yet, you can try and do a factory reset (http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-rhyme-verizon-wireless/howto/318231.html).  If not, it's likely a hardware issue.